# Can food of purely mineral origin be considered vegan?

Tags: veganism, is-it-vegan

Natural salt is of mineral origin, thus does not involve animals thus is vegan.

But how about a chemical of purely mineral origin? E.g. Can [synthetically produced L-Ascorbic acid](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ba-1982-0200.ch001) from ingredients that are purely mineral be considered vegan?

(I understand it's definitely not raw vegan as the T° in some of these chemical reaction exceeds 48°C)

<sub>Note: L-Ascorbic acid is Vitamin C in human...</sub>

Comment: Is there any reason you're thinking it wouldn't be vegan?

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm a chemist by education but not a vegan ...  Just wondering as I have some vegan friends!  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: If something is not non-vegan, there is is vegan. There's no in-between. Is vacuum vegan? Yes, yes it is.

Comment: Simple to someone who is vegan, confusing to someone who is not, but clear now!  **:-)** @ecc

Comment: @Fabby Naturally. IMO there is no gray zone, but one can draw the line in how much animal input one accepts (see the debate about honey, animal manure, farming fatalities...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR**: if no animals are harmed and no animal products are used, then yes, it's considered vegan.

A product of "purely mineral origin" will be considered vegan if no animals are exploited in the process of producing it, since, as vegans we avoid using animals and animal products for our own ends wherever possible.

As far as I know, the synthesis of L-Ascorbic acid doesn't involve the use of animal products; vitamin C supplements I have seen are labelled as vegan (with the exception of gelatin capsules)

However, the article you link to is interesting:

> Following   the  isolation  of  crystalline  "hexuronic acid" from the adrenal cortex  of the  ox and from orange juice in  1928  [...]  efforts were begun  to synthesize this  novel  vitamin...

This highlights the history of animal experimentation behind vitamin supplements, and, to me, the fact that veganism is in a sense aspirational, since in the last analysis it's impossible to avoid some degree of responsibility and complicity in causing suffering to other animals.

Comment: Yes, the discovery of Vitamin C is shrouded in animal experimentation, but current Vitamin C is of purely synthetic origin. **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**

Answer (score 4):

Something edible made by sticking uranium ore into a machine and cooking it for 3 days at 100000 degrees (no I haven't a recipe) would still be vegan if no animal derived ingredient or auxilary substance (except maybe bullshit use to heat it - definitions differ here!) is intentionally consumed in making it. The occasional fly falling into the crucible also does not matter; if the taste RELIED on the fly flavoring it we are in definitions-differ territory again (figs come pretty close to that...).

TL;DR: The "vegan" status of a food or other product is 100% dependent on what is consumed to make it, not on a nutritional, food treatment, religious purity based, or culinary philosophy.