# Can I tell whether E-numbered food additives are animal derived?

Tags: veganism, is-it-vegan, labeling, food-additives

Cadbury Oreo Chocolate flavor contains [E322](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_number) as an emulsifier. I searched on the net and found that it can be plant or animal derived. So how do I know whether this product is vegan or not?

And can packaged foods sold in India carrying the green dot [vegetarian mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetarian_and_non-vegetarian_marks) contain food additives that are animal derived?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **ask the producer** to determine whether any animal-based food additives were used.

The rules for the green dot [vegetarian mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetarian_and_non-vegetarian_marks) are [defined](https://www.fssai.gov.in/dam/jcr:61b5ecf1-7a41-4185-8485-4a7f68f71c2b/Compendium_Packaging_Labelling_Regulations.pdf) by the Food Safety and Standards Authority of India (FSSAI). All food is considered vegetarian unless it contradicts this definition:

> “Non-Vegetarian Food” means an article of food which contains whole or part of any animal including birds, fresh water or marine animals or eggs or products of any animal origin, but excluding milk or milk products, as an ingredient;

Note in particular that **milk and milk products are permitted** as ingredients in vegetarian foods bearing the green dot. The green dot doesn't necessarily mean that a food product is vegan.

E322 is normally derived from either soy or egg. Since egg products are not permitted according to this legislation, E322 is very likely going to be of plant-origin if the product has the vegetarian mark.